# Google Tag Manager Not Sending Ecommerce Data to Analytics (Standard Ecommerce)

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have been racking my brain on this one and not sure why our Google Tag Manager code isn't sending data to our Google Analytics account.

I have researched multiple questions on here that have similar issues, but haven't worked for me.  In addition this is a great guide I've followed https://www.analyticsmania.com/post/ecommerce-tracking-with-google-tag-manager/ - but still no luck in sending the ecommerce data to GA.

Below is the data layer that we're using on our /ticketing/confirm/ page where our customers go when they complete checkout:

```
    <script>
        dataLayer = [{
            'theatreLocation': 'xxxx',
            'theatreState': 'xx',
            'userID': '0',
            'userEmail': 'xxx',
            'movieTitle': 'xxx',
            'transactionId': 'xxx',
            'transactionTotal': xxx,
            'transactionProducts': [
            ]
        }];
    </script>
```

These variables are automatically updated based on the product that is purchased. This tag is also placed above our Google Tag Manager script, which fires just below this one.

Within Google Tag Manager, we have an ecommerce tag connected to our GA account that is a transaction type tag.  This tag is set to fire on a trigger of the order confirmation URL.  At this point the data should be sending to GA

Tag setup - https://i.stack.imgur.com/BvukE.png
Trigger setup - https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vwYV.png

When checking an order confirmation page with the tag manager extension, it shows our tags being fired on page view of the confirmation page: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qC8Y5.png

View of the overall summary: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqfsX.png

Detailed view of the eCommerce tag: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WT6oo.png

I also have the tag assistant extension installed and here is what that looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYXN2.png

And the detailed view of the Analytics tag: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mutrk.png

According to the article I linked above, the detailed view of that analytics tag within tag assistant should have an "other event" listed which should be the transaction info being sent to GA - but as you can see from our screenshot mine does not have that.  I'm not sure where I'm going wrong as I think I have everything setup correctly, but clearly there is a break somewhere.

Any help or input is really appreciated.

Comment: Can you make changes to the dataLayer structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the settings variable from the tracking ID field in the tag setup. Assuming you want to use the tracking ID you set in the settings variable, uncheck the option to override the settings variable.

If you do want to override the tracking ID from your settings variable, this needs to be a string or variable that returns a tracking ID and not an entire settings variable.

Comment: thanks - that was the solution - i had to manually enter in my analytics tracking ID in the tag setup. thanks!