# Ecommerce data not passing from Google Tag manager to Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-datalayer, enhanced-ecommerce

I cannot figure out why Google Tag ManageR is not sending Enhanced Ecommerce dataLayer through to Analytics.

My issue is very similar to this question: [Google Tag Manager Not Sending Ecommerce Data to Analytics (Standard Ecommerce)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56564810/google-tag-manager-not-sending-ecommerce-data-to-analytics-standard-ecommerce)

GTM is properly sending pageviews to Analytics, just not transaction data.

Our custom 'transactionComplete' event properly fires when we want. It shows in the Tag Debug panel and dataLayer looks good, keys match documentation: https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/enhanced-ecommerce#purchases . The datalayer shows in Tag Assistant tool for GTM.

What does NOT show is Ecommerce data, dataLayer, etc. under the Google Analytics tab in the Tag Assistant, nor does it appear in GA itself.

- GTM Tag: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJx7j.jpg
- GTM Trigger: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mt5D2.jpg
- GTM Variable: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1IaCB.jpg
- Tag Debug Event Tags: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cdcng.jpg
- Tag Debug Event Vars: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2HkrF.jpg
- Tag Debug Event Data: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnw2i.jpg
- Tag Assist GTM Data: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2VuHw.jpg
- Tag Assist GA: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IgyaQ.jpg

It looks like in the last image, in Tag Assistant for GA, we're missing the 'Other Event' listing with transaction data sent to GA.

Any ideas at all?

Answer (score 2):

Standard ecommerce and enhanced ecommerce are two different type of data, which can be sent to Google Analytics. Track type 'Transaction' is used for standard ecommerce, while enhanced ecommerce can be sent as a payload with a pageview or an event hit. Currently you are trying to send enhanced ecommerce data with 'Transaction', which seems to get ignored.

If you look at the tag settings directly at an event, you can enable Enhanced ecommerce. 
[image]

If you look at the tag settings of a transaction, you won't find this same setting. 
[image]

GTM seems to be a bit misleading, as it seems to simply ignore your ecommerce selection in the Google Analytics setting variable, without any warning. You can verify this with Google Analytics Debugger Chrome extension, or by using Network tab in Developer Tools, where you can examine all the payload values, which get sent to Analyitcs.